# Problems accessing files on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have problems recording a wav file on my Android app on the emulator which can work previously. I didn't change the code but the emulator just cannot create the wav file for me when I record it. However, when I tried it on my Android phone, it works fine.

In addition, I also cannot push in a wav file into my emulator using DDMS->File Explorer.

Does anyone met this kind of problem before?

Comment: are you trying to push in sdcard or application's app data ?

Comment: I'm trying to push in sdcard's data.

Comment: Please ensure that sdcard is attached with emulator.

Comment: Okay. Now my emulator decides to work again after not working for the past week. >.< I have no idea what caused the erratic behaviour...

Comment: How do you make sure sdcard is attached to the emulator?

Comment: when you open DDMS -> FileExplorer you see one sdcard folder.

Comment: Yup. It's always there but it hasn't been working for the past week until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that file handling on the emulator can be unpredictable occassionally. Most of the time it is fine, but I have experienced permission problems from time to time. I usually just create a new emulator instance now so everything gets initialised from scratch. It can be irritating but this has solved my occassional problems. I have searched the web and found seemingly good fixes, but the problem still re-occurs from time to time. Fortunately, it has not been long lasting.